# Incompatible pointer types initializing 'AVMutableMetadataItem *' with an expression of type 'AVMetadataItem *'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I can not understand what the problem is before it worked

```
 - (NSString *)titleForAudioFileModel:(APAudioPlayerModel *)audioFileModel {
    AVPlayerItem *avItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioFileModel.filePath]];
    NSUInteger titleIndex = [avItem.asset.commonMetadata indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        AVMutableMetadataItem *metaItem = (AVMutableMetadataItem *)obj;
        if ([metaItem.commonKey isEqualToString:AVMetadataCommonKeyTitle]) {
            return YES;
        }
        return NO;
    }];

    if (titleIndex == NSNotFound) {
        return @"";
    }
    AVMutableMetadataItem *item = avItem.asset.metadata[titleIndex];// Incompatible pointer types initializing 'AVMutableMetadataItem *' with an expression of type 'AVMetadataItem *'
    return (NSString *)item.value;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you are trying to assign to your `item` variable is declared as:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSArray <AVMetadataItem *> *metadata
```

That means the compiler expects that every item in the array will be of the type `AVMetadataItem`.  This class is the superclass for `AVMutableMetadataItem`, and you can't assign a reference to a superclass to a variable of a subclass.

The reason it may have worked before is that the SDK and compiler did not always support generics (the `<AVMetadataItem *>` in the property declaration).  It would have worked so long as you didn't treat `item` as mutable.

The fix is to either change the type of `item`, or to assign a `mutableCopy` of `avItem.asset.metadata[titleIndex]`.